# Jenkins Pipeline - input only if branch matches

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I want to ask for input but only if we are on a certain branch.  But the input is run before the when. Can this be done with declarative syntax?

For example this will always prompt even when the branch is not master

```
stage('only on master') {
   when {
      branch 'master'
   }
   input { ... }
}
```

Comment: Use beforeInput like specified in the docs https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two approaches  :

### Save current branch name on a variable and check it in a if statement

```
CURRENT_BRANCH = '...' // some value or parameter

stage('only on master') {
  if (CURRENT_BRANCH == 'master') {
  input {
    ...
  }
}

// be sure to check if input was set or define a default value
```

or

### Run a shell script to know if current folder is a git repo on master

The following command check if current folder is a git repository  printing "true" ( or returning a error if does not have repo)

```
git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
```

The next, print the current branch name

```
git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

Use both to create a script that sets an environment variable.
Check the value on your pipeline, to show the input

```
stage('only on master') {

  // Set true on IS_ON_MASTER if current branch is master, 
  // otherwise set false

  sh ./check-branch-master.sh 

  if (env.IS_ON_MASTER) {
  input {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add closing bracket "}", which are missing in the first and last code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use the `beforeInput` flag

```
stage('Example Deploy') {
        when {
            beforeInput true
            branch 'production'
        }
        input {
            message "Deploy to production?"
            id "simple-input"
        }
        steps {
            echo 'Deploying'
        }
    }
```

[Jenkins pipeline | When](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when)